# Limitations on incrementing values (standard sql)

Tags: sql, increment

Given a table of students and grades, is there a way to increment each student's grade by 10%,  but without going over 100?

Right now I do

```
UPDATE studentCourse
SET grade = grade + 10 * (grade/100) 
WHERE csid = 1
```

In other words, if a student has 60, after the update he should have 66. But if a student has a 98, after the update his grade should be 100 (and not 108).

All this has to be done in standard SQL

Comment: Don't you mean 66 should become 72.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could you just run two statements

```
UPDATE studentCourse
SET grade = grade + 10 * (grade/100) 
WHERE csid = 1;
```

followed by

```
UPDATE studentCourse
SET grade = 100
where csid = 1
  and grade > 100;

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an instance to test this code on, but assuming your data is realiable (all 0 - 100) you could use a CASE statement in the case the score is below 90 to add the 10% as you already are, otherwise in the other case we can say the score will be 100.

E.g:

```
UPDATE [studentCourse]
SET grade=
(
CASE
  WHEN
  (grade <= 90)
    THEN grade + 10 * (grade/100)
  ELSE
    (100)
  END
)
WHERE
csid = 1
```

Comment: I so much more like you original answer without the "sneaky" edit just in order to be the "oldest correct" answer. Still. I upvoted :)

Comment: Grade should be less than or equal to 90
(grade <= 90)

Comment: I thought I'd better back it up with an example ;) Good point on the <= 90.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a function `LEAST()` that can help:

```
UPDATE studentCourse
SET grade = LEAST(100, grade + 10 * (grade/100))
WHERE csid = 1;
```

This `LEAST()` function is MySQL-specific.  If you want to be strictly ANSI SQL compliant, use `CASE` as suggested by @chrisc.